# How to create a 4 section flex layout which collapses only on screen resize

Tags: css, flexbox

I am attempting to create a flex layout as illustrated in the screenshots below.
This is what the page will look like on normal screen size (before resize).

[image]

Page resize will look like this, with sidebar over main content.

[image]

The code I have written appears to work. However, how can I make the sidebar fall under the main content when screen size is reduced?

CSS:

```
    div#container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    main{
        display: flex;
        background-color: #ccc;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 80vh;
    }
    header {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    footer {
        background-color: #F2F2F2;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    section#content {
        background-color: #D62121;
        width: auto;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    section#sidebar {
        background-color: green;
        width: 350px;
    }
    
    /* For demo purposes */
@media (max-width: 815px) {
    section#sidebar {
        width: 100%;
    }
    main{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <p>HEADER</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="content">
            <div>
            <!-- Add long text here and main content falls below sidebar.-->
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="sidebar">
            <h1>Sidebar</h1>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Async, you are looking for the CSS flexbox 'holy grail' layout. Found here on SO. Most likely variations on the 'MDN holy grail flexbox' layout. Here's my version on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/pJpMrB) (an oldie, with a few FBL additions. Heavily commented, though).

Comment: This is indeed very helpful and possibly an answer. I was also able to change the order in the media query which puts the side bar under the main content. `order: -1;`

Comment: Without any modifications, your FBL elements will have `order: 0` (as in: not defined with CSS, default HTML document order). Smartest way to go would be: choose your default layout (either desktop or mobile) and modify the layout with MQ's for the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

header {
    background-color: coral;
    height: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
    background-color: coral;
    height: 100px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

section#content {
    background-color: #D62121;
    flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 380px);
    max-width: calc(100% - 380px);
}

section#sidebar {
    background-color: green;
    width: 350px;
    flex: 0 0 350px;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* For demo purposes */
@media (max-width: 815px) {
  section#content,
  section#sidebar{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
section#content {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  section#sidebar{
    order: 1;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
 }
```

The layout breakage was because of the `flex-grow:1`. After setting its flex-grow to the initial value and setting its maximum width `flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 380px)` in it. The layout will stop expanding to its max-width and text will break accordingly.
I hope this will help. Please review in js fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/chhiring90/8xmvy4ur/

Comment: Thank you! Looking at the fiddle, I see that the sidebar is still falling under the main content. I would like the the sidebar to stay on top of the main content when the size of the page is reduced.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated its order in the breakpoint. I'm glad to help.